# Error when calculate field using VBscript or Python (slice a field)

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

I have an expression in VBscript that works well for labeling:

```
Function FindLabel (field)
 if (INT(RIGHT(field, 2)) <> 1) then
   FindLabel = INT(MID(field, 8, 3)) &"-"& INT(RIGHT(field,2))
else
    FindLabel = INT(MID(field, 8, 3))
end if
End Function
```

This expression labels a text in this format: **VCC065-00102** to: **1-2**  or from **VCC065-00501** to: **5** (using just the last 5 carachters, if the last one is > 1, it shows the number after a "-").

But, when I tried to use the same script for **calculating a field**, I've got a syntax error error:

**Code block:**
the same as above

**Expression:**

> FindLabel ([DATA])

Also, I tried to convert this script to Python:

**Code Block:**

```
def FindLabel (Field):
  Var1 = Field[-2:]
  Var2 = Field[8:-3]
  if (int(Var1)  <> 1 ):
    FindLabel = int(Var2) &"-"&  int(Var1)
  else:
    FindLabel = int(Var2)
```

**Expression:**

```
FindLabel (!DATA!)
```

But it returns an error:
*The field is not nullable.*
(I don't know why, but the expression is returning a null value)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried selecting just a single record and running your script above to confirm it works?  If you run the script on the entire dataset, and have *even one* record where !DATA! is blank or null, it could throw this error if the output field is not nullable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Python code isn't actually returning a value, so that's why you are getting the not nullable error.

You need to use the `return` statement instead. Additionally, use `+` to concatenate strings instead of `&`:

```
def FindLabel (Field):
  Var1 = Field[-2:]
  Var2 = Field[8:-3]
  if (int(Var1)  <> 1 ):
    return str(int(Var2)) + "-" + str(int(Var1))
  else:
    return str(int(Var2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!
Problem solved.
Also, I found other errors (on slicing and I needed to convert to string to concatenate):

```
def FindLabel (field):
  Var1 = field [-2:]
  Var2 = field [7:10]
  A = int(Var1)
  B =  int(Var2)
  if (int(Var1)  <> 1 ):
    return str(B) + "-" +  str(A)
  else:
    return str(B)
```

Comment: I think you should Accept Answer from @EvilGenius but leave this one here too